# How can a massive object fit inside a much smaller container?

Tags: magic, gods

The Old Gods were entities responsible for the creation of reality. They had been worshiped by civilization for millennia as gods, until an ancient war forced many of them into a deep slumber. One, called, Y’GOLONAC,  has been awakened in recent times and seeks to undo reality, returning it into the chaotic realm it once was. A great hero has set out with a powerful weapon to slay the god and save the world. Killing it would not be enough however, as the creature is immortal and will simply return at some point, perhaps stronger than it is now.

To deal with the threat permanently, the creature's soul must be contained in a vessel to prevent it from escaping. The problem is that the soul of the entity is massive, and too powerful to be contained. Trapping it inside a human or object would simply destroy the vessel shortly after. This is similar to a balloon filled with too much air, or a human imploding from too much pressure.

A witch developed a ritual to contain the god that involves relations with the hero, while also giving her access to the god's power. After he killed the creature, its soul was transferred to the child that they have conceived. This child contains the soul of the god within itself, and is being raised by the witch for her own purposes. This would indirectly make her the most powerful individual on the planet.

How can the soul of an entity be too massive to fit inside a grown human, but manage to fit inside a much smaller vessel?

Comment: Are we talking about physical volume, or some other woo-woo "largeness" quality? I mean, there are entire mountains that could contain such a thing if inanimate objects are an option.

Comment: You mean like the Tardis?

Answer (score 5):

You can use *Tabula rasa* theory. From Aristotle *De anima*. When the child is born it's soul is clean. And is child is growing up his slate is being written by his experience and knowledge he gain.
Adult can have some things written in him as in stone. If a powerful soul would inhibit such human it power could erase or destroy those thing destroying human in the process.

A child give chance for the soul to fill everything with itself while allowing for some external influence.

Answer (score 4):

It’s all a matter of defences.

An adult soul is old. It’s gnarled and worn. It’s dealt with learning how to survive. It’s seen heartbreak and known pain.

And in response it’s hardened into a solid, defensible shape. It’s learnt mechanisms for deflecting or pushing away the worst the world has to offer. Outwardly these defences manifest as sarcasm, or emotional repression, or addiction. Inwardly it’s metaphysical batteries of cannon, steel walls and spikes. These things are strong, but when they break they *break*, and they’re so entwined with the soul that trying to deal with the sheer power of a god ***breaks*** not only those defences, but also the soul they surround.

A child’s soul is innocent. It has no defences. No metaphysical immune system. When a god is placed inside a child’s soul it can ‘stretch’ more, since it simply doesn’t know that boundaries exist yet. By the time the borders of the child’s soul start to learn how to weather the storm that is existence the god is already firmly in residence, not only giving shape to the soul but also bolstering those very same defences. A child that would have been sarcastic learns to be cruel instead. A child that would have been withdrawn becomes sociopathic.

And the few gates through the defences; like love, kindness and empathy?

The god closes those forever.

Answer (score 1):

A child is the perfect vessel for this. Children have a soul potential much greater than a grown human. As we age our soul capacity shrinks and becomes more specialized/concentrated.